# Angularjs assign a ngmodel of element when template is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive("mydirect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "mytemplate.html",
    }
});
```

The template from `mytemplate.html` is:

```
<input ng-model="name{{comment.ID}}" ng-init="name{{comment.ID}}={{comment.Name}}"  />
```

I load the template several times and for each time I want to change the variable assigned as the `ng-model`, for example `ng-model="name88"` (for `comment.ID == 88`).

But all the loaded templates have the same value.

But when I change `comment.ID`, all inserted templates become the last ID changed.

Comment: try this : name[{{comment.ID}}]

Comment: yep, such templates is invalid - you can not use {{}} for variable names

Comment: Are you saying that you want to dynamically determine what `ng-model` is bound to? Sometimes it's `$scope.name88` and sometimes it's `$scope.name53`? Can you give a broader picture of what you are trying to do? How is this directive used?

Comment: **think about this approach** http://plnkr.co/edit/pPmyYQEu5h1739T4J2O0?p=preview

Comment: @kaneda, ok. **why** do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I load load several times the template after ajax request to get a Id, so i don't want the Inpute element of the template have the same ng-model.

Comment: Edit you original question with broader context of why you doing this, and what you are actually trying to build. You may be asking an [XY question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). For example, you may be able to bind to an object: `name[comment.ID]`, or create an isolate scope.

Comment: I changed the question, hope you can understand. Sorry :(

Comment: @kaneda, I edited your question in an attempt to clarify - let me know if the edit makes sense

Comment: ho yes :), it's that! Thanks very much... my english is too bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot put expressions, like `name{{comment.ID}}` in `ng-model` - it needs to be assigned to a variable.

So, let's change the template to:

```
<input ng-model="comment.ID" ng-init="comment.ID = comment.Name">
```

It's not entirely clear what you mean by "load the template". If you mean that you create a `mydirect` directive for each `comment` object, then you are probably doing this (or at least, you should be) with something like `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat = "comment in comments">
  <mydirect></mydirect>
</div>
```

This is convenient - `comment` is both the variable used in the `ng-repeat`, and the variable used for the directive's template. But this is not too reusable. What if you wanted to change the structure of the `comment` object? And what if you wanted to place multiple directive's side-by-side, without the child scope created for each iteration of `ng-repeat` and assign a different `comment` object to each?

For this, you should use an isolate scope for the directive. You should read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-), but in the nutshell, the way it works is that it allows you specify an internal variable that would be used in the template and bind it to whatever variable assigned to some attribute of the element the directive is declared on.

This is done like so:

```
app.directive("mydirect", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
           // this maps the attribute `src` to `$scope.model` within the directive
           model: "=src" 
        },
        templateUrl: '<input ng-model="model.ID">',
    }
});
```

And, let's say that you have:

```
$scope.comment1 = {ID: "123"};
$scope.comment2 = {ID: "545"};
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
<mydirect src="comment1"></mydirect>
<mydirect src="comment2"></mydirect>
```

Alternatively, if you have an array of comments, whether you create them statically or load from a service call, you could just do this:

```
<div ng-repeat = "comment in comments">
  <mydirect src="comment"></mydirect>
</div>
```

Comment: Great it's work :D. Thanks you very much. For each new comment I increment a variable nbComment :    
eval('$scope.comment' + nbComment + ' = response.data');   And pass to compile   $compile('<displaycomment src = "comment' + nbComment + '" ></displaycomment>')($scope)

Comment: @kaneda, that is probably not the right way to go. Use the `ng-repeat` method and just `.push` the new `comment` into the array.